# Is it possible to show combinined social likes & shares?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

I want to make a counter which uses the various social APIs (either JS/PHP) which can show a 'total' of Fb likes, tweets, shares etc but then shows the count per network on rollover for instance:

```
+-----------------+
| Loved 345 Times |
+-----------------+

then on rollover:

+-----------------+
| Loved 345 Times |
+-----------------+
| 300 Facebook    |
+-----------------+
| 30 tweets       |
+-----------------+
| 15 Pins         |
+-----------------+
```

Question: is this possible simply through Javascript considering that each API is kind of sandboxed?

Thanks very much

Comment: Make API requests to each. When all are done, combine the numbers and store the information somewhere (JS, HTML, whatever), so that it can be brought up on hover. Try something out and let us know what problems you're having

Comment: ahah.. sounds good, do I need to make an app etc in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to look into Sharedcount api if your requirements are not to get Live data every time, this works greate in Jquery.
You can also make individual request to each api(Via PHP, as google and twitter does not allow Cross Domain) - create a wraper class call, this will calculate individual counts over you server.

Similar Implementation - http://www.saladappstore.com/page/social-analytics